# how to submit the form on before unload from the test page in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

how to submit the form in rails if the user refresh the page or pressing back button . I need alert message are you sure you want to quit the test ? like this if they press okay then the page should be submitted .

Answer (score 0):

you could handle close tab, refresh page, change page with [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload) like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```